# Please help identify this beautiful piece of music played by legendary violinist Ida Haendel

Tags: identify-this-song, classical-music

Please help identify this beautiful piece of music played by legendary viloinist Ida Haendel. The music is on Youtube:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sr9fOXyT70M
Ida Haendel plays the violin accompanied by the piano from 1:12 to 5:21 minutes:seconds. Possibly a movement from a violin sonata .
Shazam cannot identify.
Beautiful and haunting.
Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is "Prayer", arranged by Carl Flesch from Handel's *Dettingen Te Deum*

Edit:
Here is a recording of the original Handel. https://youtu.be/aufEH9xJK_k?t=2060

Comment: Thank you so much. And for the link to an original recording.

Comment: @Andrew, much appreciated if you would please "accept" the answer. Thanks kindly.

Comment: not sure how to?

Comment: @Andrew: instructions are here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. Cheers.